# PHP, how to format DateTimeInterface for mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, datetime-format

When I write a php `DateTimeInterface` to mysql `timestamp` field, I always do:

```php
$datetime = (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$sql = "... when_inserted = '$datetime'";
```

I know that [`DateTimeInterface::format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) supports Full Date/Time formatting (`c`, `r`), but both of them produce a warning on mysql

`c`: `2023-03-22T11:33:40+01:00`

mysql warning: `Data truncated for column 'when_inserted' at row 1`

`r`: `Wed, 22 Mar 2023 11:33:40 +0100`

mysql warning: `Data truncated for column 'when_inserted' at row 1`

Is there a shorter way or I must format the date with the boring and verbose `Y-m-d H:i:s`?

Comment: You could change your Database DateTime Markup, or you just leave it with Y-m-d....
I'd take the second option, and if it disturbs (writing the YMD..) you, make a function now() or smth.

Comment: i often just use date('Y-m-d H:i:s')

Comment: You could define a constant once, `define('MYSQL_DATE_FORMAT', 'Y-m-d H:i:s');`, and then use that throughout your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the format `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` is correct for MySQL. Unfortunately, there is no built-in method or constant to get this format.

To optimize your workflow, you could define the format as a constant yourself and use it throughout your project.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`__toString()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) magic method if you don't wish to write those format statements everytime and wish to inject a string representation of an object automatically when the object gets used in a string context.

To do this, create your own Custom class and make it a child by extending the `DateTime` class and implement __toString() method in it and use it in your sql variable like below:

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

class CustomDateTime extends DateTime{
    public function __toString(){
        return $this->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
}

$datetime = new CustomDateTime();
$sql = "... when_inserted = '$datetime'";

echo $sql;
```

[**Online Demo**](https://3v4l.org/JGaN5)

Answer (score 0):

The Mysql NOW() function may be your solution.

```
$sql = "... when_inserted = NOW()";
```